# Correct usage of 'overflow: hidden' and 'position: absolute'

Tags: html, css

I created a container inside another container that has `position:absolute` and `top:100%`. This container is used to be some kind of fade-out-container, so it actually has no real content.

[image: little content]

Now when this containers height exceeds the browser windows height, a scrollbar appears. And this is exactly what should *not* happen.

[image: much content]

Instead I thought I could apply `overflow:hidden` on body or the parent container, but either too much gets cut off or the fade-out-container itself becomes invisible.

[image: overflow hidden on body almost does the job]

Please have a look at my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tpygoq2h/3/) and tell me what I'm missing. Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <h1>Demo</h1>
</header>
<footer>
  <p>
  The orange container wraps the blue one.<br/>The blue containers' height is meant to be cut off of the browser window meaning it's overflow should get hidden if the browser windows' height is insufficient.
  </p>
  <p>position: relative;<p>
  <div class="append gradient">
    <p>position: absolute;<br/>
    top: 100%;<br/>
    left: 0;<br/>
    width: 100%;<br/>
    height: 100%;</p>
  </div>
</footer>
...
```

**CSS**

```
body {background: 333;}

header, footer, .append {
  font-family: consolas, console, courier, arial, helvetica;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

header {
  background: #666;
  }
footer {
  background: #F86; 
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  }
.append {
  background: #66F;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  left: 0;
  }
```

**EDIT**: updated fiddle, added inline code, added images

Comment: I couldn't see that you applied `overflow:hidden` anywhere...

Comment: I didn't downvoted your question.

Comment: I didn't down vote but voted to close because questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**

Comment: @Manticore, if you actually read my comment carefully I said I didn't downvote you and as you see I have now retracted my vote to close as you have added the code to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you give `top: 100%` with a `position: absolute`, then you are actually sending it fully to the next page. I guess you are trying to make a modal-window, then you need to set it as:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
```

The above code will over everything. The `overflow: hidden` is not applicable here, but when you are planning to show the modal window, or the overlay, it is best to use `overflow: hidden` to the `<body>`, so that the users will not be able to scroll and you can find the modal window.

Explaining the whole concept I said using a snippet here. Click the links to invoke the modal window. Click the opened modal window to hide it back. Scroll and see. Play around with it:

```js
$(function () {
  $("body > p").append(' <a href="#">Open Modal</a>');
  $("p a").click(function () {
    $("body").addClass("modal-open");
    return false;
  });
  $(".mask").click(function () {
    $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
  });
});
```

```css
.mask {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 999;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
.mask p:first-child {
  padding-top: 5em;
}
.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.modal-open .mask {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mask">
  <p>Click the links to invoke the modal window.</p>
  <p>Click the opened modal window to hide it back.</p>
  <p>Scroll and see. Play around with it</p>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda vitae temporibus corporis, quisquam, doloremque excepturi itaque laborum ratione sequi aliquid atque rerum rem minima, aperiam laboriosam blanditiis alias ex quas?</p>
<p>Quam dolor, perspiciatis! Perspiciatis voluptatibus magnam ad hic sint, officia voluptates aut labore, excepturi quasi sed sit modi amet temporibus exercitationem laudantium veniam cumque omnis quo! Esse, quas! Harum, iure!</p>
<p>Illo optio alias amet ex consequuntur est autem itaque reprehenderit odit, laboriosam saepe ipsa harum eligendi sit cumque modi cum perspiciatis! Dolorum, alias nostrum asperiores velit atque perferendis voluptatibus. Maiores!</p>
<p>Cumque perspiciatis laudantium sequi itaque eos facilis illum repellat necessitatibus sunt recusandae rem, tempore blanditiis consectetur distinctio nostrum enim sit corporis non odio deleniti architecto. Corporis, nam assumenda. Quibusdam, perspiciatis!</p>
<p>Illum, quasi nisi animi. Expedita recusandae nam maxime architecto, illo a? Aspernatur numquam eveniet quisquam, inventore fugit amet voluptatem porro odio corporis obcaecati nostrum earum aliquam recusandae, sint necessitatibus rem.</p>
<p>Id praesentium vitae tenetur harum voluptate error adipisci dignissimos vero voluptatibus numquam quibusdam, nemo molestias alias aliquam, est, esse at fugiat quasi ducimus ratione! Inventore, eaque repudiandae sed magnam incidunt!</p>
<p>Aliquid in, veritatis ut! Veritatis, voluptatibus? Fugiat iusto officia repellat quasi dolore eum odio vitae inventore error debitis, doloribus facilis, itaque! Perspiciatis iste, incidunt hic non qui voluptate rem quidem?</p>
<p>Explicabo laudantium quidem, ab aperiam autem tenetur quae voluptatem quam, mollitia recusandae sapiente id, praesentium quasi soluta tempora dolorum, maiores velit. Porro unde doloribus iste, nihil ipsa, pariatur molestias aliquam.</p>
<p>Aut excepturi vitae dicta, quos distinctio, nulla, nostrum architecto, atque veritatis perspiciatis voluptates odio. Similique nobis sed natus illo esse, quod quas ex tenetur dolore deserunt optio voluptate numquam quo.</p>
<p>Repudiandae inventore consequatur nisi ad ut voluptas pariatur ducimus consequuntur, exercitationem tenetur ipsam nesciunt beatae nostrum soluta similique excepturi perspiciatis consectetur illum veniam aut hic, neque eveniet. Nesciunt quas, placeat?</p>
<p>Unde nam, aut placeat. Voluptas, consequatur, quis. Perferendis illum ratione in voluptate consectetur molestias nam hic, reprehenderit similique distinctio. Repellendus veritatis excepturi hic dicta fuga mollitia! Culpa dolores doloribus, ratione.</p>
<p>Vero cupiditate quaerat sit non veritatis harum nesciunt eos suscipit tempore dolorem porro saepe a, iusto vitae, voluptatum debitis consectetur voluptas, corporis. Sequi, sint odio eligendi delectus culpa dignissimos, obcaecati?</p>
<p>Ipsam sequi facilis magnam ad officiis quae, nobis iusto, commodi culpa optio a facere numquam placeat perspiciatis saepe maxime mollitia voluptatem sunt ipsa? Sequi ipsam, nostrum blanditiis dicta repudiandae iste!</p>
<p>Facilis tenetur officia quo delectus eius quam vel minus quas nesciunt ipsa perferendis, explicabo quasi itaque, rem vero accusamus debitis quis pariatur blanditiis illo nostrum eum! Molestiae fuga eius, illum.</p>
<p>Accusantium, repellendus soluta modi animi cumque error, nemo doloremque. Commodi voluptates distinctio nesciunt animi a, odio assumenda exercitationem amet reprehenderit libero expedita fugit. Id minus, corporis quibusdam cupiditate aut harum!</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Actually I am just building a gradient that should "hang" on the footer. But it should be cut off instead of being scrollable. It should only be seen if the page content has not enough height to fill the browser height.

Comment: @Manticore Check my updated code. Also please provide a working example. Lemme see your fiddle and update it.

Comment: I have updated my fiddle above. I don't know if you get me right. I don't want modal, but thanks for that ;) I want simply a decorative element that doesnt trigger scrollbars.

Comment: @Manticore The solution is same. Check my answer.

Comment: I don't see how the solution could be the same. These are two totally different pairs of shoes. I read your answer carefully, maybe you should read my question carefully, too...

Comment: @Manticore Okay, I will again go through your question. That doesn't mean that you can vote it down for the effort I made?

Comment: Edit your answer and I will vote it up again. Sorry I was foolish. I can simply not understand how my question gets voted down while answers who have no relation get voted up. Thats bizarre!

Comment: @Manticore How am I affected? I didn't vote your question down! `:(` This is demotivating. I have edited my question, please remove the downvote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98212/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-manticore).